# Kind of singularity with Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+2z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I computed the power series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+2z}$ around point z = 0: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^nz^n$. Hopefully it is right :D

Now i have to specify the kind of singularity at $z_0 = -1/2$ (With the consideration of the Laurent series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)$ of $f$ around $z_0= -1/2$). I tried to compute first $a_{-1} = \pi i$.

My question is now should i go further and try to compute $a_{k}$ with $k≤-2$ and determine the pole order or is there a chance to get the Laurent series from my series above to determine the order from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $-\frac12$, you have$$f(z)=\frac1{1+2z}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{z+1/2}.$$Therefore, the Laurent series of $f$ centered at $-\frac12$ is $\frac12\cdot\frac1{z+1/2}$ and so $f$ has a single pole at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) But I still don't get it how this is associated with the Laurent series of $f$. What am i missing ?

Comment: What I did proves that the Laurent series of $f$ near $-\frac12$ is$$\cdots+0\times\left(z+\frac12\right)^{-3}+0\times\left(z+\frac12\right)^{-2}+\frac12\left(z+\frac12\right)^{-1}+0+0\times\left(z+\frac12\right)+\cdots,$$right?!

Comment: I got it, Thank you !